# The nature of Entropy in the Gibbs free energy in thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, entropy, diffusion

I struggle with understandinng the Gibbs free energy $G$ for a very long time now. I still managed to pass the thermodynamic courses, but this lack of understanding haunts me till today.

So finally I want to understand it. My problem is based on two different treatments of $G$ I always encounter, which look like they contradict each other. Maybe I just overlooked assumptions or simplifications...

$\textbf{First treatment:}$

The Gibbs free energy is the maximum work, which can be extracted from a system. To calculate it, the inner energy $U$ is reduced by the expansion work $-pV$, resulting in the enthalpy $H$, and the not usable random thermal energy $TS$. We obtain $G = U + pV - TS = H - TS$. This interpretation basically says that $U$ already contains $TS$, which is then removed with $- TS$ such that $G$ does not contain $TS$ anymore. This treamtment can be found here [“Internal energy”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_energy#Internal_energy_of_multi-component_systems) in section "Internal energy of multi-component systems" in which only $U$, but not $G$, depends on $TS$.

$\textbf{Second treatment:}$

When $G$ is used for calculations in textbooks, $H$ is often treated without considering any entropy and entropy contributions are instead collected in $-TS$. For example in a diffusive jump, $G_M$ is the Gibbs energy of migration and always split into $H_M$ (Migration enthalpy, which is equated with the activation energy) and $-TS_M$ with $S_M$ being the migration entropy (This treatment can for example be found here [Lattice diffusion coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_diffusion_coefficient)).

The second treatment contradicts the first treatment, because in one $H$ is dependent on $S$ and in the other not? Is there a simple way to understand this?

Comment: I do not understand your question/problem. Just because $TS$ and $pV$  formally "removed" from $U$ does not mean that $G$ now becomes independent of $S$ and $V$. In fact, you now have $dG=-SdT+Vdp+ \delta W^*$ instead of $dU=TdS-pdV +\delta W$, in other words you have *interchanged* the independent and dependent variables from $S  \leftrightarrow T$ and $V  \leftrightarrow p$. This is the Legendre transform of these variables in which $\delta W^*=\delta W$ numerically but not functionally, that is $\delta W=\sum_k \mu(S,V,N_k)dN_k$ and $\delta W^*= \sum_k\mu^*(T,p,N_k)dN_k$.

Comment: with $\mu=\frac{\partial U}{\partial N_k}$ and $\mu^*=\frac{\partial G}{\partial N_k}$. The chemical potentials $\mu$ and $\mu^*$ are defined completely differently and are different functions.

Comment: You understood the question very well! Does that mean that the $H$ in $G=H-TS$ is indeed fully independent on $S$ and that the second treatment is correct? Guessing from your answer my confusion was then that $G = H - TS$ is not only the subtraction of $TS$ from $H$ but also a coordinate transformation from $H(S)$ to $H(T)$?

Comment: Ah, now I think I understand your question! When you write $U=TS-pV+\sum_k \mu_k N_k$ and also $dU=TdS-pdV+\sum_k \mu_k dN_k$ you also *know* that $T=T(S,V,N_1,N_2,..), p=p(S,V, N_1,N_2,..), \mu_k=\mu_k(S,V,N_1,N_2,..)$. Therefore, writing $G=U-TS+pV=\sum_k \mu_k(S,V, N_1,N_2,..)dN_k$ does not make the variables $S,V$ magically disappear, they are still there! Now if you also make the "coordinate" transformation you get $dG(T,p,N_1,N_2,..)=-SdT+Vdp+\sum_k \mu^*_k(T,p,N_1,N_2,..)dN_k$.

Comment: And for the special case of constant temperature and constant pressure: $dT=0, T=T_0; dp=0, p=p_0$ loved by chemists you have $dG(T_0,p_0,N_1,N_2,..)=\sum_k \mu^*_k(T_0,p_0,N_1,N_2,..)dN_k$. Is it clear now?

Comment: It is definitely more clearer, thank you very much! The only thing I still struggle with is how the dependence on S can be reduced to $-TS$. Very stupid analogy: A function $f_1(x)=x^2$. Now I create from this a new function $f_2(x)=x^2-ax$. Even with a coordinate transformation I cannot shift the full dependence on $x$ away from $x^2$ to $-ax$. Maybe I just dont understand Legendre transformations.